# UML Diagrams and Omnis Studio 5 or 8

Tags: uml, rad

Is it possible to generate UML diagrams directly on Omnis studio (tigerlogic) 5 or 8 through some external component maybe ? I was thinking about a class diagram and a sequence diagram...

Comment: You can RE code with most of the professional tools to create class diagrams. SDs can only be created from running code (which is also supported by some of the UML tools).

Answer (score -1):

I've experimented something with the OBrowser and some external JS library, but for now it only has limited support to the class diagram, feel free to look at https://github.com/GiacomoManzoli/OmnisDocUML.

The basic idea is to use the Omnis introspection utilities like `$cclass.$methods`, `$cclass.$ivarsdef` and `$methods.[methodName].$lvarsdef` to define the class field and methods. 
Then to use the `$superclass` and the vars definition to define the relationships with other classes.
Once the class is correctly represented in Omnis, you can parse the definition in a graphical language, such has DOT (like i did) or [nomnoml](https://github.com/skanaar/nomnoml).

For the sequence diagram i have not did anything yet, maybe something can be done by accessing the method lines or text and parsing the `Do` and `Do method` commands.

Comment: Do not post a link to a tool or library as an answer. Demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself. Do [edit] the answer, and flag for undeletion once you have added the demonstration.